# why can't this wxPython frame (and a panel inside) keep its size?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, panel, frame

***The background colour of panel is applied to the whole frame! why'd that be happening, I wonder. Here, frame is (300,400) whereas the panel is supposed to be (300,180). I might be doing something wrong.***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import wx

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pos, size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size) 

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
        self.userpanel = Panel(self, -1, (0,0), (300,180))
        self.userpanel.SetBackgroundColour('Gold')


class Application(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        frame = Frame(None, -1, "Internet Login Tool", (-1,-1), (300,400),\
        wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a panel to a frame it takes up the whole area of the frame, add a panel to the frame and then add your panel to the frames panel as shown in your modified code below

```
import wx

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pos, size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size) 

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
        framePanel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.userpanel = Panel(framePanel, -1, (0,0), (300,180))
        self.userpanel.SetBackgroundColour('Gold')


class Application(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        frame = Frame(None, -1, "Internet Login Tool", (-1,-1), (300,400),\
        wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: More specifically, when a wx.Frame has only one child (other then menubar, toolbar and statusbar) then that child is automatically resized to fill the frame's client area.